# Is there a way to instantiate objects from a dictionary in python with input parameters?

Tags: python, templates, dictionary

Say I have some class:

```
class Object1:
   def __init__(self, input=None):
       pass

class Object2:
   def __init__(self, input=None):
       pass
```

I can probably define a dict like this:

```
objDict = {"a" : Object1(), "b" : Object2()}
```

This would instantiate objects with input of None.
Is there a way I could use the dictionary as a template though so I could pass in a parameter? Like this:

```
firstObj = objDict["a"]("foo")
```

And if this is possible, would this be the best way of doing it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also can you give more details on exactly what you are aiming for? I'm not sure I completely understand. Give some inputs and outputs.

Comment: `... the best way of doing it?`  - it really depends on what you are trying to achieve, what problem are you trying to solve, how you plan on using it.  You haven't explained any of that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating the class when you make the dictionary, which isn't what you want.  Just put the classes as values:

```
class_dict = {"a": Object1, "b": Object2}
first_obj = class_dict["a"]("foo")
```